# Sorting\Ordering data using thymeleaf

Tags: spring, jpa, thymeleaf, selected

I'm developing a virtual learning platform with courses. Currently, I have some courses and now I want to sort them for example by title in ascending or descending order. Now I'm not able to connect the thymeleaf with my sorting functions.

Courses Html Page code:

```
    <!-- Courses -->

    <div class="courses">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="select">
                <select id="orderSelect" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option selected value="ratingAsc">Order by Rating Ascending</option>
                    <option value="ratingDesc">Order by Rating Descending</option>
                    <option value="titleAsc"> Order by Title Ascending</option>
                    <option value="titleDesc">Order by Title Descending</option>
                    <option value="totalVotesAsc">Order by Total Votes Ascending</option>
                    <option value="totalVotesDesc">Order by Total Votes Descending</option>
                    <option value="membersAsc">Order by Members Amount Ascending</option>
                    <option value="membersDesc">Order by Members Amount Descending</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="row courses_row">





                <!-- Course -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 course_col" th:each="course: ${allCourses}">
                    <div class="course">
                        <div class="course_image"><img src="../static/img/course_6.jpg" th:src="@{/img/course_6.jpg}"
                                                       alt=""></div>
                        <div class="course_body">
                            <div class="course_title">
                                <a href="course.html" th:href="@{'/courses/'+${course.id}}" th:text="${course.title}"
                                   th:alt="CourseTitle">
                                    Course title
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="course_info">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="instructors.html" th:href="@{instructors}">Sarah Parker</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" th:alt="Topic">English</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="course_text">
                                <p th:text="${course.description}" th:alt="Description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                                    consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce enim nulla.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="course_footer d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                            <div class="course_students"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>10</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="course_rating ml-auto"><i class="fa fa-star"
                                                                  aria-hidden="true"></i><span>4,5</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row flex-row">
                <ul class="nav-pills">
                    <li class="col-lg-4 mt-auto"
                        th:each="i:${#numbers.sequence(0,allCourses.totalPages -1)}">
                        <a th:href="@{/courses(page=${i})}" th:text="${i+1}" class="nav-link"
                           th:classappend="${currentPage}==${i}?'active':''"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class CoursesController {
    private CourseService courseService;

    @Autowired
    public CoursesController(CourseService courseService) {
        this.courseService = courseService;
    }

    @GetMapping("courses")
    public String showCoursesPageSorted(Model model,@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "titleAsc") String sortBy){
        model.addAttribute("allCourses", courseService.findBy(page,sortBy));
        model.addAttribute("currentPage",page);
        model.addAttribute("currentSort",sortBy);
        return "courses";
    }
```

The only solution that I figured out so far was to create a new HTML page for every single filter but it doesn't look right..

Comment: best option is to sort either at database query level (best) or at object level (good).

Comment: I'm sorting in the CourseRepository interface using the JpaRepository like that:  
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Long> {

    Course getById(long id);
    Page<Course> findAllByOrderByAvgRatingDesc(Pageable pageable);
    Page<Course> findAllByOrderByAvgRatingAsc(Pageable pageable);
    Page<Course> findAllByOrderByTotalVotesAsc(Pageable pageable);
    Page<Course> findAllByOrderByTotalVotesDesc(Pageable pageable);
    Page<Course> findAllByOrderByTitleAsc(Pageable pageable); 
   Page<Course> findAllByOrderByTitleDesc(Pageable pageable);

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have planned for database pagination and sorting support. That's a solid approach for growing data.

**Repository**

First of all, you don't need separate repository methods (as you have shown in a comment) to sort courses by different fields. Instead, have one method that takes filter criteria (if any) and `Pageable`. `Pageable` has `page (int), size(int), and sort(object)` fields.

```
Page<Course> findCourses(Pageable pageable);
```

**Controller**

*Pageable is manually created*

In the `Controller` method, take individual parameters: `page, size, sort` OR `Pageable`. In case you have a Pageable object, use the same to call the repository method. In case you have individual params from the front end, construct Pageable yourself:

```
public String getCourses(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int
    page, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int size, 
    @RequestParam(defaultValue = "title") String sortBy){
    // Some code
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(sortBy).ascending());
    repository.findCourses(pageable);
    // Rest of the code
}
```

*Pageable is made available in the Controller*

If you want to rely on Spring to get the Pageable object directly in the controller ensure these request parameters are passed - `page, size, and sort` (example: `page=0&size=10&sort=rating,asc`). The sort parameter may be passed multiple times to sort by multiple fields if needed.

```
public String getCourses(Model model, Pageable pageable){
  // Some code
  repository.findCourses(pageable);
  // Rest of the code
}
```

Now, to show courses in a paginated manner and sorted by various fields you need to have only one HTML page and one single grid.

**Future Extension**

In the future, you may add search courses as well. In that case, you have to add search criteria field in the controller and the repository.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Is this approach providing a sorting for all the pages? I mean I'm not sure how to make it sort all the courses in all the pages. Currently, when I request to sort the courses by title for example, it sorts the first page, but when I go to the second page, courses are not sorted.

Comment: @IvanNickSim yes, this will sort data across all pages.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do all sorting on your controller side. But if you still want to do sorting  using thymeleaf, you can use utility method  [list](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#lists) provided by thymeleaf.

```
${#lists.sort(list)}
${#lists.sort(list, comparator)}
```

and use as below.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 course_col" th:each="course:${#lists.sort(allCourses)}">
```